# NestJS can't resolve dependencies of the UserController

Tags: typescript, nestjs

### Current behavior

Trying to use my **UserService.ts** and **AuthService.ts** in my **UserController.ts**, but I get the following error:
`[ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserController (?, +). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the current context.`

### Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions

application.module.ts

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ApplicationController } from "controllers/application.controller";
import { ApplicationService } from "services/application.service";
import { AuthModule } from "./auth.module";
import { UserModule } from "./user.module";

@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
  ],
  controllers: [
    ApplicationController,
  ],
  providers: [
    ApplicationService,
  ],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

user.module.ts

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { UserController } from "controllers/user.controller";

@Module({
  controllers: [
    UserController,
  ],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { InjectRepository } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { Repository } from "typeorm";
import { UserEntity } from "entities/user.entity";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
    private readonly repository: Repository<UserEntity>,
  ) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
    return await this.repository.find();
  }
}
```

auth.module.ts

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { JwtModule } from "@nestjs/jwt";
import { AuthService } from "services/auth.service";

@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.register({
      secretOrPrivateKey: "key12345",
    }),
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { JwtService } from "@nestjs/jwt";
import { TokenJwtInterface } from "interfaces/token-jwt.interface";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private tokenType;

  constructor(private readonly jwtService: JwtService) {
    this.tokenType = "bearer";
  }

  public generateTokenJwt(
    payload: object,
    expiresIn: number,
  ): TokenJwtInterface {
    const accessToken = this.jwtService.sign(payload);

    return {
      access_token: accessToken,
      token_type: this.tokenType,
      refresh_token: "",
      expires_in: expiresIn,
    };
  }
}
```

user.controller.ts

```
import {
  Get,
  Controller,
  Post,
  Body,
  HttpCode,
  HttpStatus,
} from "@nestjs/common";
import { UserService } from "services/user.service";
import { UserEntity } from "entities/user.entity";
import * as bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { AuthService } from "services/auth.service";

@Controller("/users")
export class UserController {
  constructor(
    private readonly userService: UserService,
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
  ) {}

  @Get()
  async root(): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
    return await this.userService.findAll();
  }
...
```

### What is the motivation / use case for changing the behavior?

Bugfix?

### Environment

Nest version: 5.1.0 
For Tooling issues:
- Node version: v8.11.3
- Platform:  Ubuntu
- IDE: VSC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `AuthService` must be part of your `UserModule`

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { UserController } from "controllers/user.controller";

@Module({
   controllers: [
     UserController,
   ],
   components: [
     UserService,
     AuthService
   ],
   imports: [
     AuthModule 
   ]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

I always thought that `import`ing some module would be enough, but in my experience I always had to declare it in the `components` section.

I also realized that you forgot to declare your `UserService` in your components' module